# FFmpeg's AAC ("libfaac") Codec Options?

Tags: video, ffmpeg, video-processing, video-encoding

For AAC ("libfaac") audio encoder, how can I specify the "MPEG Version" to either "MPEG-4" or "MPEG-2" through FFmpeg's command?

Comment: I see that some encoding software can specify mpeg2 or mpeg4 as AAC's codec option and it is based on ffmpeg, so I think there is a command to specify this, but I can't find out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using libfaac, FFmpeg hard-codes the MPEG version to MPEG-4. You can observe this in `libfaac.c`, line 118.

```
faac_cfg->mpegVersion = MPEG4;
```

If you want to change it, you will have download the FFmpeg source, modify this line to use `MPEG2` instead, and recompile FFmpeg with the appropriate configuration (including `--enable-libfaac`). This works and produces a playable file, however you'll obviously have to use a bitstream filter to create a valid bitstream for MPEG-4 containers now:

```
ffmpeg -i in.wav -c:a libfaac -absf aac_adtstoasc out.m4a
```

If instead you use the FAAC API directly, you can of course change this parameter as you wish.

---

Ideally, one would submit a patch for FFmpeg to include a new option which allows you to set this manually, but given that MPEG-4 was chosen as a hardcoded default I don't see a compelling reason to implement this.

Comment: When do I need to use '-absf aac_adtstoasc'??

Comment: You need to use it when you're encoding an MPEG-2 versioned AAC bitstream that you want to package in an MPEG-4 container, because ADTS is the bitstream format for MPEG-2 AAC.